# Duplicate api's listed by the help page

Tags: asp.net-web-api-helppages

I am using the webapi help pages nuget package from Microsoft.

When i recently added a new controller, all my routes in the help page appear twice:

```
GET api/v2/something/{id}
```

and

```
GET api/v2/something?id={id}
```

How can i remove these duplicates?

Surprisingly for some older controllers that i added last year that did not happen.

The only difference that i can think of is that in the new controller i used `dynamic` as the response type, but i also used the `ResponseTypeAttribute` so in the help page the DTO models are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Swagger/Swashbuckle instead of the WebAPI help pages. You can install it via nuget. It will create a SwaggerConfig.cs in the App_Start folder. There might be some minor tweaks that you have to make depending on your requirements. Just check the documentation.

Comment: yes, we now about swashbuckle; however the choice was made for the api nuget, and i was hoping there is an answer for that package.